# Facebook redirection to site url rather than the app url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've having problem with Facebook redirection, when I login to facebook redirected from getLoginUrl(), I sends me to the site url rather than the app url. When I check the redirect uri in the URL, it is the site url.

I used the code below to change the URL,

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos,friends_photos',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/myappname'
));
```

But now rather than redirecting me to Facebook login page for my app it gives me an error as,

An error occurred with [App Name]. Please try again later.

I don't know where I commited mistake. Would be glad for a response.

Thanks in advance :)

Prakash

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to redirect to the secure url : https://apps.facebook.com/myappname

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can only redirect to the same domain and path of your application

"The redirect_uri must be in the path of the Site URL you specify in Website section of the Summary tab in the Developer App. If it is the root of the domain, it should end with a trailing slash. Note, your redirect_uri can not be a redirector." in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/